# Google Cloud Build doesn't trigger on Github push, builds old commit when triggered manually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have defined a simple configuration in Google Cloud Build that mirrors a github repository and triggers when I push to `master`. However, for some time, the build is not triggered anymore when I push. And when I trigger the build manually, an old commit is built.

Deleting and recreating the trigger didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug on Google's side but here's a workaround how I was able to fix it.

First, delete your Cloud Build trigger.

Then, navigate to [Google Cloud Source Repositories](https://source.cloud.google.com/). You should be able to find the repo that is mirrored from Github. Click on the settings icon next to repo and then click on "Disconnect this repository".

Now, recreate the trigger from scratch.

Comment: I am glad you found a workaround. I have also found [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121232316) which looks like a known issue. Follow, mark as affected and add your own comment to get further updates there.

Comment: I'm getting `Failed to connect repositories` so i guess it has something to do with GCP talking to Github :(

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for saving my day with this answer!!