# Cloud build triggers not triggered anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

It's about a week that our triggers on new tags from github don't automatically start anymore.

Is something changed or is there anything to check why are not starting anymore? Since before everything went ok and we did not change anything in our `cloudbuild.yaml`s, manually they run without issues.

Comment: Have you tried recreating your trigger as described in this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180076/google-cloud-build-doesnt-trigger-on-github-push-builds-old-commit-when-trigge)?

Comment: Not this time. I mean I did last time that even the manual action was not performing on new tags. I was hoping in some kind of "official" way,  when occurs, of knowing the causes

Comment: It looks like an expected behaviour as the tags are new and not present when cloud source repositories mirrored the repo. Which [version of Cloud Build triggers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-github#different_types_of_github-based_triggers) you are using and what are the trigger settings? That could allow us to see how your triggers should be starting in order to try replicating it. 
There might be also something in your `cloudbuild.yaml` that worth checking, please add it to the description