# Cloud build with bitbucket repository sync

Tags: git, google-cloud-build, bitbucket-cloud

I'm using Cloud Build to deploy some cloud functions and the original repo is hosted on bitbucket cloud.
I've mirrored the repo, created a trigger to start the build process and everything is working, but I have to do a manual sync to have the same content on both repos. Is there a way to have them synchronised automatically?
I can always do a pull inside the Cloud Build script, but it doesn't work when I change the Cloud build .yaml file. Any other way to overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you mirrored it?

Comment: Hi @ChristopheKalt, the mirror is "automatic" to Google Cloud Source Repositories (CSR) when you enable Cloud Build trigger from BitBucket cloud: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/bitbucket/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Cloud Build trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/triggers) automatically starts a build whenever you make any changes to your source code. [You can configure the trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers) to build your code on any changes to the source repository or only changes that match certain criteria.

You can also refer to [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automate-builds-webhook-events)  on how to Automate builds in response to webhook events.

As you have mentioned

> repo is hosted on bitbucket cloud. I've mirrored the repo

I assume you are using cloud build 1st gen for mirroring your bitbucket cloud, However as mentioned [here](https://paste.pics/a9df22c03a3b643f5dca7dd37c9b1a03), In the backend cloud build uses cloud source repositories only to sync code changes.

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository#force_a_repository_sync)

> After you set up mirroring, Cloud Source Repositories automatically syncs your repository with the mirrored repository when a user commits a change. Cloud Source Repositories lets you view the last time your mirrored repository was synced and manually force a sync if necessary.

It looks like an issue with sync between CSR(Cloud Source Repository) and Bitbucket cloud.

Hence, Try to disconnect your BitBucket repository and then reconnect the repository by creating a new trigger or deleting the connection in Cloud Source Repository and then adding the same repository again.And also have a look at [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/google-cloud-repositories-bitbucket-mirroring-issue/qaq-p/2228169) which might help you.

Comment: Thanks Sathi!
I rebuild the connection with the repository and it now syncs automatically, but there is one gotcha ... the deployment is always one sync delayed. When I do a change in one file, it triggers the build, but the build is based on the CSR previous configuration.
On the next build, it does the same, so always one deploy behind.
it seems that the sync is triggered, but Cloud Build uses the existing files which didn't had time to update.
Any suggestion? Is this the "normal" behaviour?

Comment: check sync status in CSR to make sure it completes before triggering the build, check the logs if there are errors or [warnings.As](http://warnings.As) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180077/18265638) try to  recreate the trigger